# How to get friend of friend details from facebook iOS SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, facebook-graph-api

Currently i am working in getting facebook friends details. Now i need to know that, is it possible to get the **friend of friend** details using facebook SDK or graph API? If it is possible, please give the way to get the friend of friend details.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After Authorization stuff ...

Try this request ..

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"[friend_id]/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

You will get the friends of any friend ..

Answer (score 0):

This is from latest SDK 2.8

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/{user-id}/friendlists"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];
```